# Access htaccess of another website

Tags: html, apache, server

How do I download an htaccess file from another website?

How do I view my own htaccess in my browser?

I have tried to go to www.website.com/.htaccess but no success for example.

I know that there is a command that can be added to the htaccess file to disable viewing but I'm talking about htaccess files that do not include this code.

Answer (score 7):

By default, Apache config has

```
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

So you can't, or you shouldn't be able to. It would be a security problem otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I download an htaccess file from another website?

That's not possible, `.htaccess` can contain sensitive information, that's why the default configuration prevents access to this file.

> How do I view my own htaccess in my browser?

You can modify the server configuration (see [how to configure apache to view hidden (`.`) files?](https://serverfault.com/q/245922/212545)) to unblock access to this file. But if you have access to this configuration, you probably have an access to the file, so you should be able to view it with another tool than your browser.